# Simple program for making shifts

Tags: java

My dad asked me to make a program for him that will randomly take a name, surname etc. from Excel (or CSV file) and assign employees to the work. Each person must be at work minimum once and maximum 4 times a month. Program output should look like this:

> Day 1: John Smith, James Smith
>  Day 2: Charlie Smith, Thomas Smith

And this is how my code looks like right now

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String FileName = "excel.csv";

    File f = new File(FileName);
    String read = "";

    Map<Integer, Surname>SurnameArray = new HashMap<Integer, Surname>();

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            read = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] arraySplit = read.split(",");
                int kod = Integer.parseInt(tablicaSplit[0]);
                String rank = tablicaSplit[1];
                String name = tablicaSplit[2];
                String surname = tablicaSplit[3];

                SurnameArray.put(kod, new Nazwiska(kod, rank, name, surname));
                SurnameArray.get(kod).getAll();

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No file!");
    }

}
```

}

And the second class looks like this:

```
Class Surnames {
private int kod;
private String rank;
private String name;
private String surname;

public Surnames(int kod, String rank, String name, String surname) {
    super();
    this.kod = kod;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

    public void getAll() {
        System.out.println(rank + " " + name + " " + surname);
    }

    public int getKod() {
        return kod;
    }

    public void setKod(int kod) {
        this.kod = kod;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(String rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setNazwisko(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

I'm stuck at this moment. I think that this code is more complicated than it should be. If someone could show me how can i make it or maybe there is simpler way to make something like this.

Comment: I don't see a question here.  What is the specific problem?  YOu may want to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
    class Surnames{ 

         private final HashSet<String> EMPLOYEES;
         private ArrayList<String> positions;

         Surnames(String csv){
             HashSet<String> tempEMPLOYEES = new HashSet<>();
             ArrayList<String> tempPositions = new ArrayList<>();
             /*here the code for putting csv data ino an tempEMPLOYEE hashSet, or a static setter method doing this, as well for tempPositions, containing array list of positions remember to check 
               if the hashset's size is equal or lower than arrayList's*/
             EMPLOYEES = tempEMPLOYEES;
             positions = tempPosition;
         }

         public void printShift(){

              for(int i = 0; i < EMPLOYEES.size(); i++){
                   System.out.println(positions.get(i) + "- " + EMPLOYEES.get(i));
              }
         }

      }
```

Since hashSet gives different object position in the set every single run of the program, placing `EMPLOYEES` to `positions` will be random. I mentioned checking that HashSet `EMPLOYEES` should be less size than `positions`. I iterate on the hashset- every employee should get a position.